# Adafruit bonnet & adafruit-circuitpython-motorkit return "ValueError: No Hardware I2C on (scl,sda)=(3, 2)"

Tags: i2c, adafruit

on the line `kit = MotorKit()`, the error diagnostic is:

`ValueError: No Hardware I2C on (scl,sda)=(3, 2)`

---

quality standards quality standards quality standards quality standards quality standards quality standards quality standards quality standards quality standards quality standards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fix is to use `raspi-config` to activate the I2C port.

I'm documenting this because the interthing had no link from that misleading error message to this fix, because nobody except me forgot to activate the I2C port.

Comment: Heres a link to the solution (note that on raspberrypi 4 it does not require you to restart machine): https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/11/enabling-the-i2c-interface-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @Phlip is correct (I2C must be enabled via `raspi-config`) though you can also bump into this when trying to use other I2C ports (software or hardware) aside from the primary one.

In that case the fix is to use the [Adafruit_Python_Extended_Bus](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_Extended_Bus) library to create a custom I2C object. This worked for me for the ServoKit library.